# angularJS and IONIC - When should I use nested state？

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie on angularJS and IONIC. 
I found nested state is used popularly.

Here is a sample:

**Nested state:**

```
 $stateProvider.state('app.todos', {
          abstract: true,
          url: '/todos',
          views: {
            todos: {
              template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
            }
          }
        })

        $stateProvider.state('app.todos.index', {
          url: '/todoIndex',
          templateUrl: 'todos.html',
          controller: 'TodosCtrl'
        })

        $stateProvider.state('app.todos.detail', {
          url: '/todoDetail/:index',
          templateUrl: 'todo.html',
          controller: 'TodoDetailCtrl'
        })
```

**separate state:**

```
        $stateProvider.state('app.todosIndex', {
          url: '',
          templateUrl: 'todos.html',
          controller: 'TodosCtrl'
        })

        $stateProvider.state('app.todosDetail', {
          url: '/:todo',
          templateUrl: 'todo.html',
          controller: 'TodoDetailCtrl'
        })
```

According to my understanding, we can implement "todoIndex" and "todoDetail" as two separate states, nested state is not necessary.
Of course, if we adopt nested state, it may be more clear in the hierarchy, but is there any another reason to adopt nested state?
TNX for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

according to this really helpful [guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) about Nested States & Nested Views:

"Nested States & Views:

When the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well..."